# Route Resolver issue in angular

Tags: angular, routes, angular16

I am using angular 16 for developing a project and I am new to angular and I have two modules or say two panels in my project, asset owner and service provider. Asset owner is a free user while service provider have to subscribe to see the full features.

So the features are like :
Asset owner can post jobs and invite service providers (subscribed ones) via mail to submit proposals and bid for that job as it goes in upwork for example.
So now there is a condition in which I am stuck.
If a service provider (subscribed one) logs in and does his activity and then closes the tab without logging out then  if he comes to service provider profile he will directly be redirected to dashboard if he have valid token in his localstorage. So in this condition if the user comes to view the job details from the mail link that asset owner has sent then if he is a subscriber then he must get to see the details of the job else he will be redirected to dashboard where upgrade subscription button is there, now let's come to the issue.

So to handle the entire process I am checking the subscription details from users data which is stored in a service as userData$ and in the view job component on it's initialisation I am checking if the user is subscribed then he can move ahead else he will be redirected to dashboard. But if a user is subscribed one and he closes the tab and then he clicks on the link in mail he must be sent to the job details page which will check the userData$ from the profileService and this profileService fetches that data from server with help of token details now it will indeed take some time so to prevent the redirection (for subscribed user) I am using route resolver to check whether the userData$ is non falsy and if it is non falsy then only let the route to go to view job and the rest code works. This is working fine in normal scenario when user is a subscriber, but if user is a non subscriber and he purchased the subscription from the panel and then tries to view any job then the resolver is causing issue it is again and again redirecting the user to payment successful page whenever the user is clicking on the job name (list of jobs - can be seen to subscribed users only) and this is happening only till the page is not refreshed.

Note: the userData$ in the profileService is being updated as soon as we receive the payment successful messages from stripe.

How should I manage the flow , below is my resolver code :

```
import { inject } from '@angular/core';

import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, ResolveFn, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

import { Observable, filter, take } from 'rxjs';

import { ProfileImageService } from './profile-image.service';

export const profileDataResolver: ResolveFn<boolean> = (

  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,

  state: RouterStateSnapshot,

  profileService: ProfileImageService = inject(ProfileImageService)

): Observable<boolean>  => {

    return new Observable<boolean>(observer => {

      profileService.setImageUrl('serviceprovider');

      profileService.userData$

      .pipe(

        filter(Boolean), 

        take(1)

      )

      .subscribe(user => {

          observer.next(true);

          observer.complete();      

      });
```

Below is the routing part:

```
    path: 'managerfp',

    canActivate: [AuthGuard, RoleGuard],

    component: manageJobs,

    children: [

      {

        path: '', component: JobListComponent, data: { title: 'Manage Job' }

      },

      {

        path: 'view/:id', component: ViewJobs, data: { title: 'View RFP' },

        resolve: { message: profileDataResolver}

      },

    ]

  },
```

It is causing infinite loop kind of issue by redirecting the user to payment successful page until he refreshes the page

Answer (score 0):

you may try to change this:

```
{
  path: '',
  component: JobListComponent,
  data: { title: 'Manage Job' }
}
```

to this:

```
{
  path: '',
  component: JobListComponent,
  data: { title: 'Manage Job' },
  pathMatch: 'full'

}
```

Comment: No have already tried this and it doesn't seem to work the issue is something else.

Comment: @RohitMehra However, this `pathMatch: 'full'` has to be added. It is necessary in your case.

Comment: I agree to this and have done that but the issue is not getting resolved.